# Error on sending mail with XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Hi I keep getting the error,

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or 
custom "From:" header missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

and I changed the sendmail in the php.ini to:
      sendmail_from = 12343OHBS@gmail.com

```
  $to='12343OHBS@gmail.com';//assigns the email address to the reciever part of the script
$subject='User Comments OHBS.com';
$header='test';
$name=($_POST['Name']);
$email=($_POST['Email']);
$Question=($_POST['MessageTitle']);
// the mail, the .= function is used to add more elements to the message array
$message="Name: $name\n\n";
$message.="Email: $email\n\n";
$message.="Comment or Question: $Question";
//Wordwrap to limit each line to 100 characters
$message=wordwrap($message, 100);
//Script to send the mail
$mailSent=mail($to,$header,$subject,$message);
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you install the "big" XAMPP-package including a mailserver? Without a mailserver your XAMPP installation will always yield an error when you try to send an email.

Comment: That is correct, there must be a mail server to deliver the email.

Comment: are you sure the $header = 'test' isn't your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have stmp server configured in your xampp and running.
Try enclosing the sendmail_from value in quotes

`sendmail_from = "from@example.com"`