# How to fix Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is required. in C:\xampp\htdocs\.. on line 22 ERROR

Tags: php, xampp, mail-server

I'm new to PHP and have taken a script as an example online.
I have setup Xampp and the php is installed and working.
I've attempted to setup a local mailserver with hMailServer, however I'm not entirely sure if that's setup correctly.
Anyhow, here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

$subject="";
$detail="";
$customer_mail="";
$name="";

// Contact subject
$subject ="$subject"; 

// Details
$message="$detail";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$customer_mail"; 

// From 
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ='sean.myers92@gmail.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
echo "We've recived your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

And the corresponding HTML code:

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><strong>Contact Form </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td width="16%">Subject</td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="82%"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Detail</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="customer_mail" type="text" id="customer_mail" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I submit the form I get the error Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is required.
Any ideas what could be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

From the forums of hMailServer: http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=22039

On the IP ranges. goto the my computer ip range and untick authentication for local to external and/or external to external.

Answer (score 0):

Xampp has no Mail server build in. You'll need to set one up.

[Mail issues with PHP, Unable to send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377724/mail-issues-with-php-unable-to-send/11377748#comment14994116_11377748)

[Error on sending mail with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598705/error-on-sending-mail-with-xampp?rq=1)

alternative use another stmp server (ie googlemail) and a mail library such as PEAR:Mail or swiftmailer to establish a imap/smtp connection with login credentials

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have used hMailServer for a mail server and attempted to use google mail and local but to no avail. Any suggestions on the settings I should be using for google mail?

Comment: see http://effectivewebdesigns.blogspot.de/2010/09/smtp-from-xampp-on-localhost-using-your.html

Comment: Trying to follow this tutorial, managed to modify the php.ini which I have done previously. However it is not entirely obvious where to put the changes in the sendmail file. Have you any idea where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

its php that's not configured you can update to point to a valid smtp server
in the php.ini look up `[mail function]` this is for windows only
you may want to set up mail server locally as does not support passwords or 
use phpmailer available from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer which does support logins

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest phpmailer from this link http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list and read its gmail tutorial. for me it works from local system too :) + it's very simple tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

> /**
>        * return error string or null if success
>        */
>
> **function** authSendEmail($sendto, $replyto, $subject, $message, $namefrom=""){
>       
> //SMTP + SERVER DETAILS
>       
> /* * * * CONFIGURATION START * * * */
>       
> $smtpServer = "mail.server.com";
>       
> $port = "25";
>       
> $timeout = "5";
>       
> $username = "test@server.com";
>       
> $password = "test";
>       
> $newLine = "\r\n";
>   
>
>       /* * * * CONFIGURATION END * * * * */
>
> ```
>   /*
>   2ХХ — команда успешно выполнена
>   3XX — ожидаются дополнительные данные от клиента
>   4ХХ — временная ошибка, клиент должен произвести следующую попытку через некоторое время
>   5ХХ — неустранимая ошибка
>   */
>
>
>   //0    //Connect to the host on the specified port
>       $smtpConnect = fsockopen($smtpServer, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
>       $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 1024);
>       if(empty($smtpConnect) || $smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>       {
>         return  "Failed to connect: $smtpResponse";
>       }
>
>
>   //1    //hello server
>       fputs($smtpConnect,"EHLO servername" . $newLine);
>       $smtpResponse = fgets  ($smtpConnect);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>       $smtpResponse = fgets  ($smtpConnect);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>       $smtpResponse = fgets  ($smtpConnect);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>       $smtpResponse = fgets  ($smtpConnect);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>       $smtpResponse = fgets  ($smtpConnect);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>       $smtpResponse = fgets  ($smtpConnect);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>   //2    //Request Auth Login
>       fputs($smtpConnect,"AUTH LOGIN" . $newLine);
>       $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 1024);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='3' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>   //3    //Send username
>       fputs($smtpConnect,  base64_encode($username).$newLine);
>       $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 1024);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='3' )
>         return "Authentification failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>   //4    //Send password
>       fputs($smtpConnect,  base64_encode($password).$newLine);
>       $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 1024);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>
>   //6    //Email From
>       fputs($smtpConnect, "MAIL FROM: ".$username . $newLine);
>       $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 1024);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>   //7    //Email To
>       fputs($smtpConnect, "RCPT TO: ".$sendto . $newLine);
>       $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 1024);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>   //8    //The Email
>       fputs($smtpConnect, "DATA" . $newLine);
>       $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 1024);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='3' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>   //9 //Construct Headers
>       $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $newLine;
>       $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251" . $newLine;
>       $headers .= "To: Администратор <$sendto>" . $newLine;
>       $headers .= "From: $namefrom <$username>" . $newLine;
>       $headers .= "Reply-To: $namefrom <$replyto>" . $newLine;
>       $headers .= "X-Mailer: ".phpversion(). $newLine;
>
>       fputs($smtpConnect, "Subject: $subject\n$headers\n\n$message\n.\n" );
>       $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>
>   //10    // Say Bye to SMTP
>       fputs($smtpConnect,"QUIT" . $newLine);
>       $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 1024);
>       if($smtpResponse{0} !='2' )
>         return "Failed: $smtpResponse";
>
>       return false;
> }
>
> ?>
> ```