# Getting Error in email forwarding using php

Tags: php, email

```
            <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $to = "abpaple@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
                $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
                $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
                $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
                $subject = "Form submission";
                $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
                $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
                $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

                $headers = "From:" . $from;
                $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
                echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
                // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
                // You cannot use header and echo together. It's one or the other.
                }
            ?>


            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <head>
            <title>Form submission</title>
            </head>
            <body>

            <form action="" method="post">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

            </body>
            </html>
```

i'm working on php mail sending concept, im not getting how to solve this error please if any one can help me it will be help full for me. im getting such kind of error

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is
>   required. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Message_delivering\1.php on line 14
>
> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is
>   required. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Message_delivering\1.php on line 15

Comment: Are you running your code in xampp or localhost? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394099/how-to-fix-warning-mail-function-mail-smtp-server-response-530-smtp-authe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394099/how-to-fix-warning-mail-function-mail-smtp-server-response-530-smtp-authe)

Comment: im running in local host

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Warning: mail() \[function.mail\]: SMTP server response: 530 SMTP authentication is required. in C:\xampp\htdocs\.. on line 22 ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394099/how-to-fix-warning-mail-function-mail-smtp-server-response-530-smtp-authe)

Comment: i saw these answers yesterday but unable to solve my issue. more over im not getting what actually they are tellig to work with ip range in my computer. please can u explain me about this a bit

Comment: Use PHPMailer instead of mail().